# Does a diagonal matrix commute with every other matrix of the same size?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Does a diagonal matrix commute with every other matrix of the same size?

I'm stuck on one line of a proof that I am writing, and I would like to switch order between a non-diagonal and a diagonal matrix.

Thanks,

Comment: No. Try with matrices (in lazy notation) $A = (1, 0; 0, 2)$ and $B = (1 ,2; 3 ,4)$. $AB \neq BA$

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much, @SimonS.

Comment: @SimonS Why not make this an answer to keep this post from getting bumped later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, a diagonal matrix does not commute with another matrix. You can find simple counterexamples in the comments. For a matrix to commute with all the others you need the matrix to be scalar, i.e. diagonal with entries on the diagonal which are all the same.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much,@Franco.