# Prove a claim on a commutative property of a diagonal matrix with identical diagonal entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to show [this statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1047764/99142):

> For a matrix to commute with all the others you need the matrix to be
> scalar, i.e. diagonal with entries on the diagonal which are all the
> same.

Suppose $A,B,\Lambda$ are $n \times n$ matrices. Suppose $\Lambda = \lambda I$, where $\lambda$ is a real number. How can I show that I can move $\Lambda$ anywhere, i.e. $AB\Lambda = A\Lambda B = \Lambda AB$?

I thought about doing this, but I'm not sure if I'm right:

$$ A B \Lambda = A B \lambda I = \lambda A B I $$

Since $I$ is the identity matrix, it can go anywhere.

I'm doubtful about this, since $\lambda I$ means you multiply all elements in a matrix by $\lambda$. Can we move $\lambda$ around like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A,B \Delta \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\Delta=\lambda I$.

We claim that for any real number $\lambda$ and any matrix $A$ ,$\lambda A$=$A \lambda$
Let $\lambda A=(\lambda a_{ij})$ where $0 \leq i \leq n$ and $0 \leq j \leq n$, since
$a_{ij}\in \mathbb{R}, \lambda$ and it is a field then $\lambda a_{ij}=a_{ij} \lambda$ but
$a_{ij} \lambda$ are the entries of the matrix $A \lambda$ and then $\lambda A$=$A \lambda$.
And therefore you approach is correct
$AB\Delta=AB \lambda I=A \lambda BI=A \lambda IB$
And too you can prove the other equations.